Decompose into simple fractions over R
Decompose into simple fractions $\mathbb{R}$: $$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^9+1}$$
I decomposed it to: $$f(x)=\frac{\frac{-1}{9}}{x+1}+\frac{\frac{1}{9}(x-2)}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}(x^3+1)}{x^6-x^3+1}$$
And dont know what to do next

What do you mean by "simple fractions"?

Are you asking for a partial fraction decomposition? If so, you need to break $x^9 + 1$ into a product of linear and irreducible quadratic factors... have fun!

I didn't put it quite correctly. Rather, he meant fractions having a polynomial in the numerator and denominator of the form: ax+b and x^2+px+qx

Look, for example, on https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/partialfractions.aspx
